# Is there a particular Catholic blessing for wine (outside of consecration)?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, john-apostle, blessings

Listening to Trending with Timmerie podcast on Christmas traditions, the guest was talking about "Drinking the Love of St. John" which seems like a pretty fantastic idea.  But it seems like it a particular blessing might be more appropriate especially for a priest who has never heard of the tradition.

So is there a particular blessing I can give to a priest to use for a blessing on St. John's feast day or do we just rely on priests to come up with it?

Comment: I have provided an answer from a website, with the stipulation that it does use the term "consecrate." However this appears to be a different consecration than you refer to in your question. Here it is wine brought by the people, not wine meant for communion.

Comment: @dan, yeah, that's what I meant by consecrate.  I guess that's a vague term.  I'd heard that there's a tradition to keep a bit of the wine to add to other wine you drink throughout the year - which would be a form of consecration, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a particular Catholic blessing for wine (outside of consecration)?**

Yes there is. In fact there is a very traditional one for Christmas.

In the spirit of Catholic tradition there is a blessing for wine reserved for the Feast of St. John the Evangelist (December 27).

Here follows the centuries old blessing in Latin [(Page 312)](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf). (Modern and English translations can be found on the web.) [Traditional Blessing of Wine on the Feast of St. John](https://materdeiparish.com/2016/12/blessing-wine-feast-st-john-tuesday-december-27th/)

This blessing is said immediately after the last Gospel of the Mass of St. John in the Tridentine Mass and thus is technically outside the mass. It is also permitted to be said outside the mass altogether.

> **Benedictio Vini in Festo S. Joannis Apostoli et Evangelistæ**
>
> *In Festo sancti Joannis Ap. et Evang., expleta omino Missa majore, hoc est post ultimum Evangelium, Sacerdos, retentis omnibus paramentis, excepto manipulo, vinum a populo oblatum, in memoriam et honorem S. Joannis, qui venenum innocue sumpsit, benedicit hoc modo:*
>
> V. Adjutorium nostrum in nomine Domini.
>
> R. Qui fecit caelum et terram.
>
> V. Dóminus vobíscum.
>
> R. Et cum spíritu tuo.

> **Orémus.**
>
> Bene + dícere et conse + cráre dignéris, Dómine Deus, déxtera tua hunc cálicem vini et
> cujúslibet potus: et præsta; ut per mérita sancti Joánnis Apóstoli et Evangelístæ, omnes in te credéntes et de cálice isto bibéntes benedicántur, et protegántur. Et sicut beátus Joánnes de calice bibens venénum, illǽsus omníno permánsit, ita omnes, hac die in honórem beáti Joánnis de cálice isto bibéntes, méritis ipsíus ab omni ægritúdine venéni, et nóxiis quibúsvis absolvántur, et córpore ac ánima se offeréntes, ab omni culpa liberéntur. Per Christum Dóminum nostrum.
>
> R. Amen.
>
> Béne + dic, Dómine, hanc creatúram potus: ut sit remédium salutáre ómnibus suméntibus: et præsta per invocatiónem sancti nóminis tui; ut, quicúmque ex eo gustáverint, tam ánimæ quam córporis sanitátem, te donánte, percípiant. Per Christum Dóminum nostrum.
>
> R. Amen.
>
> Et benedíctio Dei omnipoténtis, Patris, et Fílii, + et Spíritus Sancti, descéndat super hanc creatúram vini, et cujúslibet potus, et máneat semper.
>
> R. Amen.
>
> *Et aspergatur aqua benedicta.*

> *¶Quod si benedictio illa fiat privatim extra Missam, Sacerdos, superpelliceo et stola indutus, eam conficiat modo superius tradito.*

There is also a [blessing for wine reserved for the Feast of St Blaise](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/prayers/view.cfm?id=1375) (February 3) for bread, wine, water, fruit for the relief of throat ailments [(Page 317)](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf).

> **Benedictio Panis, Vini, Aqua et Fructum** ***contra gutteris ægritudinum in Festo S. Blasii Episcopi et Martyris***
>
> *(Approbata a S.R.C. die 25 Sept. 1883)*
>
> V. Adjutórium nostrum in nómine Dómine.
>
> R. Qui fecit cælum et terram.
>
> V. Dóminus vobíscum.
>
> R. Et cum spíritu tuo.
>
> **Orémus.**
>
> Salvátor mundi Deus, qui hodiérnam diem beatíssimi Blásii martýrio consecrásti, quique eídem inter céteras grátias, hanc prærogatívam contulísti, ut, quoscúmque gútturis morbos tua virtúte curáret: ineffábilem misericórdiam tuam supplíciter exorámus, et pétimus; ut hos panes, vinum, aquam, et fructus, quæ plebs fidélis tibi devóte hódie ad sanctificándum áttulit, tua pietáte bene + dícere et sancti + ficáre dignéris: ut, qui ex his gustáverint, ab omni gútturis plaga, et quavis ália ánimæ et córporis infirmitáte, méritis et intercessióne ejúsdem beáti Blásii Mártyris tui atque Pontíficis, plenam recípiant sanitátem: Qui vivis et regnas Deus in sǽcula.
>
> R. Amen.
>
> *Et aspergantur aqua benedicta.*

Lastly there is a blessing for wine [(Page 358)](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf) that may be said at [anytime for the **infirm**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/prayers/view.cfm?id=1382). It calls to mind St. Paul’s words to drink a little wine [for the sake of one’s stomach](https://www.firstthings.com/blogs/firstthoughts/2012/05/st-paul-was-right-drink-wine-for-your-health) [(1 Timothy 5:23)](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/1%20Timothy%205%3A23)

> **Benedictio Vini Pro Infirmis**
>
> V. Adjutórium nostrum in nómine Dómini.
>
> R. Qui fecit cælum et terram.
>
> V. Dóminus vobíscum. R. Et cum spíritu tuo.
> Orémus. Oratio Dómine Jesu Christe, Filii Dei vivi, qui in Cana Galilǽæ ex aqua vinum fecísti: bene + dícere et sancti + ficáre dignéris hanc creatúram vini, quam ad sustentatiónem servórum tuórum tribuísti; ut ubicúmque fusum fúerit, vel a quólibet potátum, divína opuléntiæ tuæ bene + dictióne repleátur.
>
> Omnípotens sempitérne Deus, salus ætérna credéntium, exáudi nos pro fámulo tuo infírmo
> (fámula tua infírma, seu fámulis tuis infírmis) pro quo (qua seu quibus) misericórdiæ tuæ implorámus auxílium: ut, réddita sibi sanitáte, gratiárium tibi in Ecclésia tua referat (-ant) actiónes. Per Christum Dóminum nostrum.
>
> R. Amen.
>
> *Et aspergatur vinum aqua benedicta.*

[Why is wine associated with St. John the Apostle?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/why-is-wine-associated-with-st-john-the-apostle)

[Red Wine recommendation for the Feast of St. John the Apostle?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/red-wine-recommendation-for-the-feast-of-st-john-the-apostle)

Bottoms up everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer from a website, with the stipulation that it does use the term "consecrate." However this appears to be a different consecration than you refer to in your question. Here it is wine brought by the people, not wine meant for communion:

> *At the end of the principal Mass on the feast of St. John, Apostle and Evangelist, after the last Gospel, the priest, retaining all
> vestments except the maniple, blesses wine brought by the people. This
> is done in memory and in honor of St. John, who drank without any ill
> effects the poisoned wine offered to him by his enemies.*
>
> Prayer:
>
> Priest: Our help is in the name of the Lord.
>
> All: Who made heaven and earth.
>
> P: The Lord be with you.
>
> All: May He also be with you.
>
> Let us pray. If it please you, Lord God, bless + and consecrate + this
> vessel of wine (or any other beverage) by the power of your right
> hand; and grant that, through the merits of St. John, apostle and
> evangelist, all your faithful who drink of it may find it a help and a
> protection. As the blessed John drank the poisoned potion without any
> ill effects, so may all who today drink the blessed wine in his honor
> be delivered from poisoning and similar harmful things. And as they
> offer themselves body and soul to you, may they obtain pardon of all
> their sins; through Christ our Lord.
>
> All: Amen.
>
> Lord, bless + this creature drink, so that it may be a health-giving
> medicine to all who use it; and grant by your grace that all who taste
> of it may enjoy bodily and spiritual health in calling on your holy
> name; through Christ our Lord.
>
> All: Amen.
>
> May the blessing of almighty God, Father, Son, + and Holy Spirit, come
> on this wine (or any other beverage) and remain always.
>
> All: Amen.
>
> *It is sprinkled with holy water. If the blessing is given privately outside of Mass, the priest is vested in surplice and stole and
> performs the ceremony as given above.*
>
> https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/prayers/view.cfm?id=1380

Comment: Thank you for finding this, I edited in your note there so it didn't look like a "quote only" answer